# How does Network I/O happens in node.js?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, threadpool, libuv

I have been searching about the node.js internal thread pool for I/O and found out that Network I/O does not use threads for requests.

1) Then what puts the cap on limit of network request processed asynchronously in my node.js server? I am trying to use cluster module on my octa core processor and would be using 8 forked instances. I just want to know that how many network I/O requests to 3rd party Api can each forked instance handle!

I have kind of an intuition that the network requests currently not processed might be queued in somwhere!

2) Asynchronous work like File I/O uses thread pool, how is that handled with internal thread pool of a fixed size?

How many requests(in this case, threads used) are too many?

Comment: Search Goiogle for "non-blocking networking libuv" and read some of the articles.  Here's one [How can node.js be non-blocking?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/201996/how-can-nodejs-be-non-blocking).  On Windows, networking uses I/O completion ports.  On Unix, libuv uses epoll/kqueue/select/etc.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking about file I/O.  libuv uses blocking file I/O calls, but uses native threads and a queue to offer a non-blocking interface to Javascript.  If you have more open file I/O requests than the thread pool, then a request is just queued until a thread is available.  Since the interface to Javascript is non-blocking, the queue and threads are invisible to Javascript.  A request just calls its Javascript callback when done, whether it was first queued or not.

Comment: Does the same apply to Network I/O too in libuv? I need a metric to judge how many requests would just slow down my server!

Comment: It's OS and computer specific how many network requests you can handle at once.  I've seen articles about carefully designed and configured systems  handling hundreds of thousands of simultaneously connected webSockets.  There is no particular hard limit.  It depends upon configuration and activity of the connections.  As for regular incoming http requests, it depends entirely upon what those requests are doing in your server and where the bottleneck ends up being.  You will have to discern with testing.  And, you can use node.js clustering to get more use out of multiple cores.